# PHP Variables not Calculating Correctly

Tags: php, scripting, operands

SOURCE: http://pastebin.com/mBJMGean

Variables are still not calculating correctly,
They always reset every time even with using $_SESSION variables.

This is trying to become a slideshow with 2 buttons that control 'next' and 'prev'

The variable controls are Picture ID and then the buttons control what the variable is.

it somehow loops from 3 to 1 and wont move any more.

Help is needed please. Thanks.

Comment: if you have `?>` and `<?php` in succession, might as well remove them

Answer (score 5):

You can't have any output before the session_start().  Move it up above your html and try again.

Comment: We have spent over 2 hours working on this, and you just solved our problem in seconds. Thank you so so so much.

Comment: Just a note....if he solved your problem you should click the checkmark to 'accept' his answer.